# Multiple View Controllers in a Single Window (Swift on OS X)

Tags: swift, osx, cocoa

As an exercise I want to have a single window application (in Swift on Mac OS X) with 4 views, each controlled by an independent view controller and have their own XIB file. I have working code, but I feel I've done it the wrong way, so the question is have I used a bad design pattern?

My main concern is the empty views in the main window (see first image). I want these replacing with the target views (from VC1,2,3,4), as opposed to adding the target views as subviews to the empty views.

[image]

---

```
//  MainWindowController.swift

import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForVC1: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForVC2: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForVC3: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewForVC4: NSView!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        let vc1 = VC1()
        let vc2 = VC2()
        let vc3 = VC3()
        let vc4 = VC4()

        viewForVC1.addSubview(vc1.view)
        viewForVC2.addSubview(vc2.view)
        viewForVC3.addSubview(vc3.view)
        viewForVC4.addSubview(vc4.view)
    }

    override var windowNibName: String? {
        return "MainWindowController"
    }
}
```

---

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var mwc: MainWindowController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        mwc = MainWindowController()
        mwc.showWindow(self)
    }
}
```

---

There is a Swift file and XIB for each view controller and view.

```
//  VC1,2,3,4

import Cocoa

class VC1: NSViewController {
    override var nibName: String? {
        return "VC1" // <-- swap the number here, (for VC1,2,3,4.swift)
    }

}
```

---

The end result is:

[image]

Comment: coming from iOS background , I would go with 4 containers instead of having the view of another VC,

Comment: What about the view controller for your main window? I would put that in charge of setting up the sub-view controllers, instead of using the window controller. I've also found that Storyboards make it much easier to work with multiple view controllers, especially with all the new functionality added to NSViewController. — In particular, NSStoryboard's `instantiateControllerWithIdentifier` function is what you would use to instantiate your individual view controllers.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable method. I use it myself!